# Can I track what keywords lead users to find my app on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

I know I can add a referrer parameter to the Google Play URL to track downloads from a specific source, but can I track which keyword searches users used to find my app on Google Play?

Answer (score 3):

Before Google Play, i.e Android Market, I was receiving in the referrer all the relevant information to help me understood how my app was found.

It could have been keywords, tops, similar applications, etc.
It was really, really useful.

Since Google Play, I do not receive anything anymore. The only referrers I get are the one I set manualy when I do some campaigns. I spent a lot of time trying to understand why, but it looks like Google Play just doesn't send this information anymore. Doesn't make sense to me, however.

However, you'll get keywords of how users found your application on Google Play from Google search engine (if they hit "Install on my phone" button).
**Referrer example** `utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_term=my+keyword`
(doesn't work if user is using https Google search)

Comment: i don't undertand. where can i see that information from "Referrer example"? in developer console somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, because your app is found by keywords defined by YOU.

-> If you're selling navigation based app, you may enter "navigation". Therefore it appears under keyword navigation and in that case, the result would be relevant.

If they open something related to app that is related to your app, will you be interested in the first keyword that could have been something totally different?

-> If there's an app with keyword "children", they open it and Google Play then recommends something else with children, they open it. Then, this second app, having also keyword children could have a tag "navigation". Then Google Play could recommend YOUR app. I don't believe that tag "children" would be your concern :-)

Comment: I disagree (see my answer). The keywords I was receiving when it was working were extremely useful to understand how people were finding my app.

Comment: You are right of course, about how it **used to work**, but that wasn't the question.